# Simcity 4 Yosemite

Tags: macos, games

I'm trying to run SimCity 4 Deluxe on my 12 Core Mac Pro with OS X Yosemite (10.10), but the game keeps freezing when I'm playing. Have to cmd+option+esc, and constantly save during the game so I don't lose much data. It's a pain to have to relaunch the game every 3 minutes.

Comment: Anything of interest in `/var/log/system.log` at the time of freezing?

Comment: Was trying to use the CD version... decided to just buy the updated Steam version. So far it's been running smoothly, gotten about 18 hours of gameplay without a hitch! Also was able to set up syncing my game save via drop box so I can switch between my Macs!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the CD version of this game is just too old to run on OS X 10.10 Yosemite. The solution was to purchase the updated game via Steam or the Mac App Store.